# x86 Character Output Loop

Tags: x86

I am making a x86 assembly language program and I have stored my name in the data section of the code and I would like to create a loop to output each character one at a time. I am lost at what to do for this. Any help would be great. I am new to x86. So far I have:

```
.DATA
name DWORD 4E617465h

.CODE
main PROC
     mov eax, name
 (begin my loop here)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be somewhat easier (at least conceptually) if you stored the name as a sequence of characters. Then, you could start with a pointer to the beginning of the sequence of characters, print the pointed-to character, increment the pointer, and continue looping until you've reached the end.

You'll need some way, in the loop conditional, to determine whether you've reached the end. You could either store the length of the string as a separate integer constant, *or* you could append some sort of sentinel value to the end of the sequence of characters that denotes the end of the string. Not coincidentally, this is how strings are represented in C, using a NUL character (`0`) as the sentinel denoting the end of the string.

Something like:

```
name  DB 'Nate', 00H


main PROC
    mov   edx, OFFSET [name]     ; get pointer to beginning of string

  TopOfLoop:
    movzx eax, BYTE PTR [edx]    ; get the current character

    ; TODO: print the current character in EAX however you want to do it:
    ;       calling the printf() standard-library function, making a BIOS call, etc.

    inc    edx                   ; increment pointer so it points to the to next character

    cmp    BYTE PTR [edx], 0     ; keep looping as long as the next character is not NUL,
    jne    TopOfLoop             ;  which we use to denote the end of the string

    xor    eax, eax              ; clear EAX register so we return 0
    ret                          ; return from main procedure
main ENDP
```

---

If you want to use your current code, where you've stored an integer value corresponding to the ASCII sequence of characters, you'll need to work a bit harder. Specifically, you'll need to extract one byte at a time from your packed integer value, but you'll need to do it in *reverse* order, since the x86 is little-endian.

```
4E617465 ==> 4E 61 74 65 ==> E T A N
```

Rather than actually doing the loop in reverse order, I'd prefer to reverse the sequence first, and then loop over it in a forwards direction. To do that, I'd use the `BSWAP` instruction, but you could also do it manually with a sequence of `XCHG` and `ROR` instructions (`BSWAP` is both simpler and faster). That will give you:

```
6574614E ==> 65 74 61 4E ==> N A T E
```

Then, once the digits are in the right order, we'll just read them off, one-by-one. Each time through the loop, we'll shift our temporary value *right* by 8, which will push off the processed character. We'll stop looping once the temporary value is 0, meaning that there are no more characters (bytes) left to be processed.

Something like:

```
name  DWORD 4E617465h

main PROC
    mov   edx, DWORD PTR [name]  ; load value into EDX
    bswap edx                    ; reverse the byte order for convenience

  TopOfLoop:
    movzx eax, dl                ; get the current character

    ; TODO: print the current character in EAX however you want to do it:
    ;       calling the printf() standard-library function, making a BIOS call, etc.

    shr   edx, 8                 ; shift-right by 8, lopping off the current character,
                                 ;  and queueing up the next one to process

    test  edx, edx               ; are there any more chars to process?
    jne   TopOfLoop              ; if so, keep looping

    xor   eax, eax               ; clear EAX register so we return 0
    ret                          ; return from main procedure
main ENDP
```

Comment: is there a library I would have to import so that this could be printed to the console or can I do that with a single command?

Comment: There is no single command in assembly to print things. You need some kind of library support. If you are programming on some kind of emulator, you might be able to call a BIOS or DOS interrupt to output text. In DOS, that would be `INT 21h`, service 2, and the `DL` register would contain the character to print. If you're running on a modern operating system, the easiest thing to do would be to link to a C standard library and then call something like `printf`.  @nate